# I keep receiving an Error message when adding github stats to my readme.md, how do I resolve?

Tags: github, deployment, vercel, readme

I've been trying to customize my GitHub Profile. In my discovery I found out how to add stats to my profile. In the process I keep receiving an error code. Looking for a solution to this.

---

**Error Message:**

> Something went wrong! file an issue at "my readme URL"
> Maximum retries exceeded Please add an env variable called PAT_1 with your github
> token in vercel

I have tried following along with the deployment in vercel on my own that was provided

**GitHub Repo:**
[Link to GitHub Repo for Deployment on your own](https://github.com/webdevsimone/github-readme-stats#deploy-on-your-own-vercel-instance)

**Lastly,** in my research I read that you can but your username in all **UPPERCASE** and this method, too did not work.

[Link to GitHub Profile](https://github.com/webdevsimone) to see the exact message I am receiving, as it is on my profile page.

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been resolved.
In my researched I have found that I had to make sure the maxDuration in the [vercel.JSON](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats/blob/master/vercel.json) file was set at 10 instead of 30.

Thus, causing me to have issues when trying to deploy in Vercel.